# Using .Net MAUI with MS Access DB

Tags: maui

I'm wondering if it's possible make an App with MAUI that use a MS Access DB as Database instead of SQLLite.
I did a search on Google but i didn't find anything.

Comment: MS Access is not cross platform so it is a poor choice for a cross platform app

Comment: If MS Access DB works like SQLite you can read directly MS access DB file from C# script and do your actions.

Comment: You could raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).